# Winter Bash 2016 is now live!

Tags: discussion

> [image]

You'll see a snow flake icon in top bar next to the inbox and achievements pop-up.

Visit [**FAQ**](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/faq) to know more about Winter Bash.

If you don't like this, you can opt-out from Winter Bash 2016 by clicking on "I hate hats!" from pop-up.

You can see Leaderboard for our site at [here](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/hinduism.stackexchange.com).

Comment: How can you guys hate hat :/

Comment: I hated hats, as hats are obscuring Shiva in my profile pic 

Comment: @AnkitSharma - yes , that is  the reason. Gods in profile picture.:)